# Need Step by Step guide for SVN Notifier

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a development team of 10 , we use a central repository that uses SVN , and to get notify we are planning to use **SVN Notifier for windows** so anyone make a code changes and commits a code will get **notification via email** including the commited developer.

But **i need a good video tute guide or a web site reference to setup** **SVN Notifier for windows** in latest version.

does anyone has a best guide for me to start up the process step by step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also just install [CommitMonitor](http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/CommitMonitor.html) on all your developer pcs.